# MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail takes arround 10 ms

Tags: android, memory, gridview, smoothing

We are developing an app which needs to display the camera roll in a GridView as smooth as possible. There are some examples online which help you do that, but we run into a perfectionistic issue.

When scrolling fast through the GridView the images are not directly shown on the screen. It takes some time before they appear. In our case we are currently only loading the 96*96 thumbnails which takes about 10 ms for each item.

Why is this taking so long? And are there any nice solutions to overcome this? We have already buffered the items, but the downside of this is that it waste memory.

Comment: use lazy load to display images thumbnail.

Comment: I've already used lazy loading. But I want the items to appear directly. This seems not possible, even with small 96*96 images. It always takes time to load the assets.

Comment: But the lazy load takes only one time to load and after images display as offline cache.